# When to call next on BehaviorSubject after http call?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am making an http call to authenticate a user.  Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
  authenticate(username, password) {

   const user = {username, password};
    this.username = user.username;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return this._httpClient.post<any>(environment.api_url + '/auth', user, {headers: headers}).do(x=>{

     this.isLoginSubject.next(true);
   });

  }
```

Notice, I call `this.isLoginSubjct.next(true)` in the do, but I am not sure if this is the proper place to call it.

In my login component, I have a handleLogin method, so I wasn't sure if it belongs in the success callback of subscribe.

Comment: do is ok for that. It's unlikely that you want to move it to subscribe because subscribe is usually done in place where a service is consumed, not in a service itself.

Comment: If the http get call throws an error, would do still be called?

Comment: No. If you need to force log-out a user in this situation, provide a second argument for do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in either place, since the `do` operator can run side effects like this one. The real difference is that `subscribe` will make the Observable "hot", which it doesn't seem like you want to do here, as you are just returning an observable that can be subscribed to as needed, rather than returning an active subscription.

The `do` or `tap` operator is there mostly for debugging, but it can be used to isolate side effects without activating the observable, as you are doing here.

I think estus's comment also sums it up well, so I'll include it here for good measure: "do is ok for that. It's unlikely that you want to move it to subscribe because subscribe is usually done in place where a service is consumed, not in a service itself"

Comment: Yes, that is why I wasn't sure about do because most examples I see mention it is just for logging/debugging.

Comment: Is there a preference for do or tap?

Comment: “Do” and “tap” are the same thing. You use “tap” with pipeable operators (rxjs 5.5+)